# carnivorous plants in self-watering pots?

Tags: carnivorous-plants

I have been gifted three small carnivorous plants: *Cepholatus*, *Pinguicula*, and *Nepenthes* (no species info). The growing information for all three stress that should be kept moist, so I am thinking about placing them into self-watering pots. However, I looked at some information online and have not seen any mention of self-watering pots anywhere - so is it a good idea, or not?

Moreover, the instructions for Nepenthes say "place light, but not direct sunlight", and similarly for Pinguicula, "place light, but bot direct sunlight for longer time". How much concerned should I be about this in Norway? Can I place them in an east-facing window, or even a south-facing window with direct sunlight couple hours a day?